# How to use the function merge and switch of tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, control-flow

The `merge` and `switch` may not be open to use for general users. And I have searched the source code:

- [switch](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py#L284)
- [merge](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py#L376)

There is a description in `merge`:

> Returns the value of an available element of `inputs`.

What does it mean *available*? Is it returned by `switch`? This is a demo:

```py
from tensorflow.python.ops import control_flow_ops

x_0, x_1 = control_flow_ops.switch(tf.constant(2), False)
x_2, x_3 = control_flow_ops.switch(tf.constant(7), True)
y = control_flow_ops.merge([x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(y))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### `switch`

Let's start by examining the `control_flow_ops.switch` function:

```py
x_0, x_1 = control_flow_ops.switch(tf.constant(2), False)
x_2, x_3 = control_flow_ops.switch(tf.constant(7), True)
with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(sess.run(x_0))    # prints 2
  print(sess.run(x_3))    # prints 7
```

`control_flow_ops.switch` returns a tuple of tensors, but only one of them will *have a value* (depending on the condition argument). In the example above, it's `x_0 = 2` from the first `switch` and `x_3 = 7` from the second one. An attempt to evaluate `x_1` or `x_2` will result in *Retval does not have value* error:

```py
  sess.run(x_1)  # FAILS!
  sess.run(x_2)  # FAILS!
```

In other words, `x_0` and `x_3` are *available*, while `x_1` or `x_2` aren't.

### `merge`

`control_flow_ops.merge` performs an inverse op: given a tuple of tensors, it selects the available one. Precisely, it returns a named tuple `["output", "value_index"]` of a tensor that has a value. According to the current doc, the input should contain *exactly one* available tensor, this means that your demo is strictly speaking unsupported and leads to undefined behavior. Here's an example:

```py
with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(sess.run(merge([x_0, x_1])))       # Merge(output=2, value_index=0)
  print(sess.run(merge([x_1, x_0])))       # Merge(output=2, value_index=1)
  print(sess.run(merge([x_2, x_3])))       # Merge(output=7, value_index=1)
  print(sess.run(merge([x_3, x_2])))       # Merge(output=7, value_index=0)
  print(sess.run(merge([x_0, x_1, x_2])))  # Merge(output=2, value_index=0)
  print(sess.run(merge([x_1, x_2, x_3])))  # Merge(output=7, value_index=2)
```

Both of these functions can be handy to control computation flow, e.g. `control_flow_ops.switch` gradient is implemented through `switch` itself ([tensorflow source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_grad.py#L80)).

Comment: If the number of available tensor is more than one, the doc says it will raise  an error, not unsupported.  And do you think this ops needs backpropagation, I think it is just control flow, like c++ `case` block.

Comment: I wrote "your demo is unsupported", which is true. In 1.3 it doesn't raise an error, probably will raise in 1.4. Every node participates in backprop, `switch` is no exception.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this demo.

```html
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.ops import control_flow_ops

x_0, x_1 = control_flow_ops.switch(tf.constant(2), False)
x_2, x_3 = control_flow_ops.switch(tf.constant(7), True)
with tf.Session() as sess:
  print("anchor, output:{}".format(sess.run(x_0)))    # prints 2
  print("anchor, output:{}".format(sess.run(x_3)))    # prints 7

merge_0 = control_flow_ops.merge([x_0, x_2])
with tf.Session() as sess:
  print("anchor, output:{}".format(sess.run(merge_0)))    # Merge(output=2, value_index=1)
```